# Iterate over a list of files and execute them as part of Ansible deployment

Tags: migration, ansible

I have just started looking at Ansible and I love the simplicity of it. 
I would like to implement an automated migration script with a framework that does not support migrations by default but has a REST API.

My idea is the following.

- Keep all REST Calls in shell scripts with version number

E.g.

```
/migrate/001.sh
/migrate/002.sh
/migrate/003.sh
```

I can run a 
    `find . -name "*.sh" -type f -exec bash;`

is there a better way of doing this ?
Does anyone have an idea how I could implement ruby style migrations scripts ? E.g. knowing which one the last script I executed and only execute the rest ?

Thanks for any ideas in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would at least need A few things (you've named them also):

1. A way to "remember" if a particular migration already ran
2. A list of migrations in some sort of repeatable order
3. An idempotent way of running the migrations

Taking from [Doctrine Migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html) project:

They have solved problem 1 by having a database table with a single column containing the file names of migrations already run. Comparing that to the list of files leaves all migrations that need to be executed.

They have solved nr 2 by generating migration filenames with datetime, as 20100416130422 for example. These should always be chronological and won't conflict with other developers adding migrations in the same project (possibly a problem with the incrementing numbers you used in your example).

They have solved nr. 3 with a command line tool that runs the migrations (and only executes what is needed). We run that with a regular `command` or `shell` module in Ansible.

Now I know realise naming a tool that solves the problem is pretty much cheating as an answer to your question, so here's a few ideas in Ansible:

- synchronize all your migration files to remote; do not overwrite existing files
- run your bash oneliner, with an added twist: empty the file if the migration workded: `&& > filename` (you might have to resort to `xargs` instead of `find -exec` to pull it off).

Now all succesful migrations are done, and the files are empty so running again won't be a problem. The folder containing the migrations on the remote system serves as a "storage" of the migrations already ran. This solution would scale to multiple machines in different stages of migration.

If you could live with editing Ansible variables as migrations, you could also keep the entire thing in Ansible:

```
vars:
  migrations:
    - { name: "migration1", migration_command: "some migration command" }
    - { name: "migration2", migration_command: "some migration command" }

tasks:
  - name: perform migrations
    shell: "{{ item.command }} && > {{ item.name }} creates={{ item.name }} chdir=/path/to/migrations/folder
    with_items: migrations
```

This has exactly the same effect as the rsync version, it creates empty migration files (although they would not have to be empty in this case - you could save the command output as well) in the path of your chosing on the remote. Any file that exists is skipped in the migrations array - and if a migration fails (i.e. one of the shell commands fails) the script halts and no file is created - so next time the same migration will be run again.

Note that the "vars" could come from any variables source (like group_vars files or included files) so you could have a "migrations.yml" file included from a playbook.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answered many of my questions. I will build some tests to see how this can work.